# Data Fusion Wrangle CSV with empty string

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, wrangle

CSV File to import

```
"Date","Facility","FacilityNo"
"2022-07-27 00:00:00","Goku Nursing and Rehabilitation Center-1078","1078"
"2022-07-27 00:00:00","Gohan Health and Rehabilitation Center-43","433"
"2022-07-27 00:00:00","Trunks Health and Rehabilitation Center-420",""
```

When opening the above file (located in GCS) in Wrangle I get the following error.

Failed to call connection service with status 500: field FacilityNo cannot be set to a null value

[image: 1]

As soon I put a value in that empty field in the 3rd line everything works.

What is the correct way to handle this in DataFusion?

Answer (score 1):

Google Support (ticket #40900774) was able to reproduce the problem and they submitted the issue to the DataFusion product team.

We found a workaround. Import the file as "Text" then use wrangler to parse it as a CSV.